# Clear the result set in a MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, select, procedures

I want to define a MySQL stored procedure, which returns data in the result set. Sometimes, I want to return nothing (ie, zero rows).

How can I do this? `SELECT;` is invalid, and `SELECT NULL;` returns a record with a NULL value. How to select an empty set?

Comment: `select null where 1=0`?

Comment: You need a `FROM` clause that references a valid row source, and a predicate that prevents any rows from being returned. @MarcB: I believe you need a FROM clause in order to use the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @spencer7593: yep. just tested it out. so... `from dual` works nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
mysql> select null from dual where 1=0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the DUAL keyword existed.

Comment: What is `dual` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer will work, but I prefer this approach:

`SELECT NULL LIMIT 0`

It *should* also work on for other variants of SQL besides just MySQL.